# Lexicographic Order in C

Tags: c, string, comparison, lexicographic

I am working on strings in C and I would like to ask What exactly Lexicographic Order is and how is being used in C. Which is the best way to compare 2 strings . I have read about strcmp and it's lexicographic comparison but I am confused.

Comment: If you want to know what lexicographic is, search the definition or read the tag text for "lexicographic". For C string comparison, you need to be more specific about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

`strcmp` uses lexicographic order to compare strings. That is, it follows the alphabet. In English, F comes directly before G, and Z comes directly after Y. `strcmp` takes this into account, because the characters in the ASCII table succeed in alphabetical order. A typical `strcmp` function would be

```
int strcmp(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    for (; *a && *b && *a == *b; ++a, ++b)
        ;

    return *b - *a;
}
```

It loops through the characters, while the `\0` was not seen, and the current characters are equal. As soon as the characters become unequal or the `\0` is seen, the loop is broken, and the `return` expression is evaluated. If the `\0` was seen, then both characters are equal, and `\0` - `\0` must be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Lexicographic order is the order defined by the lexicon, or the order defined by how people communicate. We English-speaking humans agree that in our lexicon the word Apple comes before the word Cat, we call it 'alphabetical order'. In your case, using strcmp, it will be the order defined by the ASCII chart, which also works out to be alphabetical as long as you use a consistent case. An 'A' is less than a 'B' because the 'A' appears before the 'B' in the ASCII chart.